# SocketChannel's connect method remains hanged if the host does not exists

Tags: java, nio

My purpose is check if a host (local or remote) is running and check if the port is open too.

I have a class with the following:

```
boolean localStatus = new ControlIpPortAddress("127.0.0.1", 61616).control();
logger.info("localStatus: {}", localStatus);

boolean remoteStatus = new ControlIpPortAddress("192.168.4.5", 8080).control();
logger.info("remoteStatus: {}", remoteStatus);
```

Where the `control` method is:

```
public boolean control(){

    logger.info("Starting");

    boolean status = false;

    InetAddress inetAddress = null;
    SocketChannel socketChannel = null;
    InetSocketAddress socketAddress = null;

    try {
        inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
    } 
    catch (UnknownHostException uhe) {
        logger.error("Error: {}, Class: {}" , uhe.getMessage(), uhe.getClass());
        uhe.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(inetAddress, portAddress);

    try {
        logger.info("1");
        socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();           
        logger.info("2");
        status = socketChannel.connect(socketAddress);
        logger.info("3");
        socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        logger.info("4");
        socketChannel.finishConnect();
        logger.info("5");
        socketChannel.close();              

    } 
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        logger.error("Error: {}, Class: {}" , ioe.getMessage(), ioe.getClass());
        return false;
    }           

    logger.info("Ending");

    return status;

}
```

When I execute my program it hangs, check the following output

```
INFO rastructure.support.ControlIpPortAddress:  26 - Starting
INFO rastructure.support.ControlIpPortAddress:  46 - 1
INFO rastructure.support.ControlIpPortAddress:  48 - 2
INFO rastructure.support.ControlIpPortAddress:  50 - 3
INFO rastructure.support.ControlIpPortAddress:  52 - 4
INFO rastructure.support.ControlIpPortAddress:  54 - 5
INFO rastructure.support.ControlIpPortAddress:  63 - Ending
INFO ructure.support.LocalHostStatusCondition:  27 - localStatus: true
INFO rastructure.support.ControlIpPortAddress:  26 - Starting
INFO rastructure.support.ControlIpPortAddress:  46 - 1
INFO rastructure.support.ControlIpPortAddress:  48 - 2
//doom - hang
```

How we can see, the *SocketChannel's* `connect` method is the problem. I already did a research on Google and the results are not clear, it says if the host does not exists or if is down, it is the default behavior, remains hang it.

Wondered if exists an adequate and elegant way, through Java itself,  to just throw an exception after to set a timeout. Even worst, seems the API does not let set an explicit timeout.

Thank You.

Comment: BTW I take how reference this link http://www.mindchasers.com/dev/ping, with some additions shown above to turn around the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't make sense. You're doing the connect in blocking mode, which either completes or throws an exception, and then putting the channel into non blocking mode and calling `finishConnect(),` which isn't required at all unless you did the connect in non-blocking mode, which you didn't. You should:

- put the channel into non-blocking mode
- call `connect()`
- select on `OP_CONNECT` with a timeout
- if the channel becomes connectable, call `finishConnect(),` and *if it returns true* continue using the connected channel: otherwise return to the select step

***OR,*** much more simply

- use `Socket.connect(address, timeout)`, e.g. `channel.socket().connect(...)`.

Notes:

1. If you don't use a timeout via one of these two methods you get the platform default timeout, which is about a minute.
2. If you use a timeout as above, it is bounded by the platform default. Contrary to the Javadoc, zero does not mean an infinite timeout, and you can't increase it beyond the platform default.

Comment: Wrong where? It doesn't use non-blocking mode, or `finishConnect()`. You made that up.

Comment: Yes, but something seems illogic, according with his link configureBlocking with true (`sc.configureBlocking(true);`) is **not** blocking, and in the API http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/spi/AbstractSelectableChannel.html#configureBlocking-boolean- is if true **is** blocking. `block - If true then this channel will be placed in blocking mode; if false then it will be placed non-blocking mode`

Comment: He's wrong about `configureBlocking(true)`. It is actually redundant, as that is the initial state anyway.

Comment: Thanks again by your support.